# Fill Color in Rectangle of iText PDF

Tags: java, pdf, colors, itext

I am making a project in JAVA in which i am working with iText. Now on one stage i want to add color to my canvas i tried following codes but they are not working

```
 PdfContentByte canvas = pdf.getDirectContent();
      Rectangle rect = new Rectangle(12,12,583,830);
           rect.setBorder(Rectangle.BOX);
           rect.setBorderWidth(1);
            canvas.rectangle(rect);
            canvas.setColorFill(BaseColor.YELLOW);
            canvas.fillStroke();
```

All things are working fine except Color.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are mixing 2 different things.

Either you define the background color of the `Rectangle` object:

```
rect.setBackgroundColor(BaseColor.YELLOW);
```

Or you use the `setColorFill()` method (as you do), but in that case you need to use the `rectangle()` method with the coordinates of the rectangle as parameters to construct the path.

Note that using `setFillStroke()` makes sense in the latter case, but it doesn't make sense in the former case. In your code sample, it doesn't make sense because you're using a `Rectangle` object.

Comment: I got my mistake. Now Please can you help me in one more thing: I got color in rectangle but it is coming above the text which was present in the rectangle. I am adding text using Paragraph().So how to make it below text @Bruno Lowagie

Comment: Right now you have this: `PdfContentByte canvas = pdf.getDirectContent();` Change that line into `PdfContentByte canvas = pdf.getDirectContentUnder();` and the rectangle will appear *under* the existing text.